Awaiting API Response within Outlook Add In getAttachmentContentAsync Function
I am trying to upload attachments from a ReactJS Outlook Add In but I can not make the code wait on the API response from the server, rather it executes JS code after immediately which is problematic if upload fails.
Here is my JS code:
const uploadOutlookFile = async (files) => {
    const options = { asyncContext: { currentItem: item } };
    const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    files.map((id) => { // files have attachment id
        item.getAttachmentContentAsync(id, options, (result) => {
            const success = handleAttachmentsCallback(result);
        });
    });
    
    if(success) {
       navigate("/uploadSuccess");
    } else {
       navigate("/uploadFailure");          
   }
};

Which calls:
const handleAttachmentsCallback = async (result) => {
    return await uploadFile(result.value.content);
};

Which then calls the API:
const uploadFile = async (file) => {
    let url = `/my/rest/url`;
    return fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: file.toString(),
    });
};

I can't add an await within the getAttachmentContentAsync() function without receiving this parse error:

Parsing error: 'await' is only allowed within async functions and at
the top levels of modules.

What do I need to change to make this work if at all possible?
